# HTML pattern vs forbiddenName

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am attempting to do password validation with angular and can't see to find much information comparing HTML pattern vs angular forbiddenName. They both essentially accept regex(or a string that is regex).

Can someone please provide some clarity on when to use which and benefits? Thanks!

Comment: I'm no expert on Angular but my first inclination is that, if you are using Angular already, you might as well use Angular's `forbiddenName`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for me, I use `regex` for parsing an `forbiddenName` for validation, simply because it's directive.

ie: Do I need to block a set of inappropriate user names? => `forbiddenName`. This can also be done with regex, but I can apply forbiddenName to the div to save some SLOC.

Do I need to strip invalid characters like !@#$%? => `regex` it up, since I still *want* the user to be able to input and handle case-by-case as opposed to blocked fully / directly.

It may be personal choice since `regex` can do both, but `forbiddenName` saves some lines of boring validaiton code